# EmguCV Application Get crash when Error Occurs "Attempted Read or Write Protected Memory. This is Often Indication that Other Memory Is Corrupt"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I am Working Window based VB.NET Project in that we use `EmguCV,Opencv,Tessaract` techniques for Image Processing, My application gets crash and say to stop Application, It May be due to

> **ATTEMPTED READ OR WRITE PROTECTED MEMORY**

this kind of error. I got the Error at Below lines

```
ImageFrame2.ROI = New Rectangle(txtLeftRight3.Text, txtUpDown3.Text, txtwidth3.Text, txthight3.Text)
                       Capturez2.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 352)
                        Capturez2.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 288)
```

I have searched many articles, I applied many Solutions like mention as Follows

Turn On DEP for all programmes,

untick from Visual studio 10-Suppress JIT Optimization,

Thread.Sleep after above code lines

Is there any solutions please mention these,thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

according to me you must set capture properties at the time of declaration. Because when you do this in real time, the application is already taking images from camera and you are again trying to use it at same time. So this exception occurs. Again this exception could occur at any random point of time during application execution.

If you could show me the entire code I could surely help you in this regard.